# window.open not working in a jsp page that displays pdf

Tags: javascript, jsp, pdf

This is part of my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="myFunction();">  
<% 
  class HeaderAndFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
   private String name = "";
   protected Phrase footer;
   protected Phrase header;
   Font headerFont = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 18, Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC | Font.UNDERLINE);
   Font footerFont = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 11, Font.BOLD);
//some code

response.reset();
     response.setContentType("application/pdf");
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=data.pdf");
     //code that uses itext to display in pdf.
```

My problem is once page is loaded ,i.e the pdf is displayed on the embedded pdf viewer the alert doesnt come.Is it because of the line `response.setContentType("application/pdf");`

I even tried document.ready but to no avail.please help.

Comment: Why dont you open that pdf in other window?

Comment: See I have a form page which is html.I pass all this details on the next page which is JSP and displays the pdf.So on this page I need to open a new window.But first I decided to try to just give an alert and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Browsers use third party plugins to display pdf. I dont think you will be able to do that since your response is set to application/pdf.

What i would suggest is to open that pdf in new window by using javascript.

To check whether your iframe is loaded try this, call the checkIframe function when your parent window loads, i mean to say `window.onload`

```
<script>
var timer =null;
function checkIframe() {

     iframe = document.getElementById('myIframeId');
     var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

     if (  iframeDoc.readyState  == 'complete' ) {

        iframe.contentWindow.onload = function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
        afterLoading();  
        };
     } 
timer = window.setInterval(checkIframe, 100);
}

function afterLoading(){
    alert("I am loaded");
}
</script>
```

Comment: currently I am displaying the pdf on an iframe.just that the popup isnt displayed.The 3rd party plugin i am using is adobe reader

Comment: @Vidic If you are using i frame then run the javascript in parent context not the iframe one. you can use window.top.alert

Comment: @Vidic yes i mean to say the parent window which contains the iframe

Comment: ah ok.let me try that.

Comment: @Vidic I would suggest to try this one from your parent window context document.getElementById("myIFrame").onload = function() { alert('loaded');};

Comment: But I will have to submit the form too.So should I check if the submit button is pressed and then exectue the alert?

Comment: your parent window contains frame or what ?

Comment: yup the parent window contains the iframe

Comment: I put the script right down(below my iframe) and when I refreshed the parent image the alert got displayed

Comment: you tried this one document.getElementById("myIFrame").onload = function() { alert('loaded');}

Comment: yes i tried it.first I put the scrript in the head,no respnse at all.next I put it after the iframe ,now whenever I refresh the parent page the alert comes,i.e before the iframe is loaded

Comment: @Vidic check this http://jsfiddle.net/p2bsw/16/ just change the src with your pdf link, beware it wont work if iframe loads from other domain due to cross origin policy